# Draw Google static map image

Tags: css, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-static-api

I am using google static map API for draw google maps image in my Angularjs Application.

[https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=Brooklyn+Bridge,New+York,NY&zoom=13&size=600x300&maptype=roadmap
&markers=color:blue|label:S|40.702147,-74.015794&markers=color:green|label:G|40.711614,-74.012318
&markers=color:red|label:C|40.718217,-73.998284
&key=YOUR_API_KEY](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=Brooklyn%20Bridge,New%20York,NY&zoom=13&size=600x300&maptype=roadmap%20&markers=color:blue%7Clabel:S%7C40.702147,-74.015794&markers=color:green%7Clabel:G%7C40.711614,-74.012318%20&markers=color:red%7Clabel:C%7C40.718217,-73.998284%20&key=YOUR_API_KEY)

Its working fine for low number of map coordinate. But if have large number of map coordinate then it is not drawing map image.

for  e.g. following will draw image for low number of coordinate but if i increase that size then it will not draw.

[Static-image](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=250x236&path=color:0xff0000ff%7Cweight:245.90,-68.92%7C45.89,-69.00%7C45.86,-69.03%7C45.82,-69.16%7C45.70,-69.01%7C45.62,-69.14%7C45.56,-69.25%7C45.46,-69.25%7C45.42,-69.43%7C45.35,-69.50%7C45.28,-69.59%7C45.27,-69.75%7C45.25,-69.98%7C45.16,-70.11%7C45.05,-70.38%7C44.92,-70.52%7C44.85,-70.61%7C44.81,-70.75%7C44.68,-70.84%7C44.53,-70.94%7C44.59,-70.96%7C44.51,-70.99%7C44.47,-71.05%7C44.44,-71.12%7C44.40,-71.19%7C44.40,-71.13%7C44.35,-71.12%7C44.27,-71.10%7C44.32,-71.16%7C44.25,-71.21%7C44.29,-71.25%7C44.32,-71.29%7C44.30,-71.31%7C44.27,-71.31%7C44.25,-71.34%7C44.20,-71.38%7C44.17,-71.39%7C44.19,-71.58%7C44.12,-71.66%7C44.13,-71.72%7C44.08,-71.75%7C44.01,-71.85%7C43.93,-71.96%7C43.87,-72.02%7C36.02,-82.43%7C35.97,-82.59%7C36.03,-82.60%7C36.00,-82.76%7C35.93,-82.80%7C35.91,-82.79%7C35.89,-82.82%7C35.87,-82.86%7C35.85,-82.88%7C35.84,-82.93%7C35.83,-82.94%7C35.80,-82.95%7C35.78,-83.03%7C35.78,-83.11%7C35.77,-83.14%7C35.72,-83.18%7C35.66,-83.34%7C35.61,-83.43%7C35.59,-83.47%7C35.57,-83.49%7C35.56,-83.57%7C35.57,-83.73%7C35.52,-83.87%7C35.50,-83.81%7C35.47,-83.81%7C35.46,-83.78%7C35.33,-83.69%7C35.22,-83.57%7C35.12,-83.55%7C35.04,-83.47%7C35.00,-83.50%7C35.02,-83.58%7C34.95,-83.59%7C34.89,-83.63%7C34.79,-83.70%7C34.82,-83.80%7C34.73,-83.88%7C34.69,-84.00%7C34.66,-84.20&markers=icon:http://192.168.1.194/public/images/g-pin-icon.png%7Csize:mid%7C45.90442554309771,-68.92184019092383&markers=icon:http://192.168.1.194/public/images/r-pin-icon.png%7Csize:mid%7C34.632748866451756,-84.18814659118652&markers=color:red%7Csize:mid&maptype=roadmap&sensor=false&key=AIzaSyCROTlQkfNOnb5oZxUTCXPvz9Dz_xwRXzo)

[image]

**Edit:-**
I am getting error for this Google Map Image URL

```
<img src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=250x200&amp;path=color:0xff0000ff|weight:244.30293238565196,-68.2665974476563|44.26430994731785,-68.59496553374657|44.20606070761473,-69.06737764312157|44.147753811174056,-69.53978975249657|44.089389261368325,-70.01220186187157|43.936105944717674,-70.34179170562157|43.82445052728625,-70.37201176400083|43.73164134868192,-70.41046391243833|43.64663847098533,-70.47638188118833|43.57743518513326,-70.66314945931333|43.44437361651832,-70.72906742806333|43.23502731999249,-71.00372563118833|43.233426444457265,-71.41571293587583|43.17977400492627,-71.70135746712583|43.04583797528442,-72.02545414681333|42.89148948825737,-72.45941410775083|43.060861371343265,-73.004150390625|43.11381613521644,-73.641357421875|42.95803046045969,-74.520263671875|43.05925574419876,-75.179443359375|43.07209774714582,-75.838623046875|43.060861003899674,-76.409912109375|43.04159327590035,-76.6845703125|42.96606994513872,-77.1240234375|42.995004641918136,-77.607421875|43.023925721405675,-78.0908203125|42.99661158276462,-78.826904296875|43.129853405408575,-79.189453125|43.08413444433945,-79.2498779296875|43.03436614889081,-79.2333984375|42.95642183628041,-79.2828369140625|42.87837867059265,-79.332275390625|42.91298726881428,-79.530029296875|42.94757644320124,-79.6673583984375|42.95802978568438,-79.8486328125|42.85180523556103,-80.15625|42.82199730461899,-80.39794921875|42.856637519467114,-80.6121826171875|42.794593516370284,-80.8319091796875|42.7849186816881,-81.068115234375|42.77524233477264,-81.3043212890625|42.57169053620841,-81.54052734375|42.39993233071362,-81.80419921875|42.33743170402784,-81.97998046875|42.266739300090855,-82.06787109375|42.151185850682765,-82.3260498046875|42.084361523979666,-82.496337890625|42.31787163983394,-83.04150072288871|43.150630239407846,-82.55810228538871|43.65508864481128,-81.87694994163871|43.80750962183118,-80.91015306663871|44.16480237740625,-79.61376634788871|44.268738635035874,-78.73486009788871|43.97851946417654,-78.40822311680358|44.06699784978547,-77.77101608555358|44.20261832258035,-76.87013717930358|44.38703098507651,-76.56182687398285|44.66586537627746,-76.27618234273285|44.92781048570904,-76.03448312398285|45.350934970260454,-75.80377023335785|45.53285201085261,-75.27642648335785|45.614369581554406,-74.91387765523285|45.62666378279735,-74.44146554585785|45.73105618069394,-74.01299874898285|46.11013137338405,-74.33160226460785|46.13754402785938,-74.63921945210785|46.263442671779885,-74.50927734375|46.34422166043787,-74.3829345703125|46.39576937322028,-74.2620849609375|46.4131936539471,-74.1192626953125|46.449539361120124,-73.9544677734375|46.48586083134607,-73.7896728515625|46.52215806620057,-73.6248779296875|46.59618976940811,-73.487548828125|46.71350244599995,-73.4271240234375|46.741691567222,-73.2183837890625|46.770293402903384,-73.0645751953125|46.758679967095574,-72.8173828125|47.16307181424742,-73.1529808779452|47.16307181424742,-73.6363793154452|47.03593412582499,-74.0538597841952|46.90849280227558,-74.4713402529452|46.780747750452306,-74.8888207216952|46.652698883018346,-75.3063011904452|46.52434611849189,-75.7237816591952|46.395689381290765,-76.1412621279452|46.26672860177734,-76.5587425966952|46.13746371630336,-76.9762230654452|46.00789466725463,-77.3937035341952|45.878021403096156,-77.8111840029452|45.836454050187726,-78.387451171875|45.706179285330855,-78.804931640625|45.50634690108343,-79.1015625|45.437008288673916,-79.29931640625|45.3212543611715,-79.82666015625|45.20526345616242,-80.35400390625|45.089035564831065,-80.88134765625|44.97257068224067,-81.40869140625|44.8558688073573,-81.93603515625|45.026950453185506,-82.55126953125|45.406163745160214,-83.5400390625|45.78284835197681,-84.57275390625|46.15700496290808,-85.60546875|46.23305294479828,-86.517333984375|46.03510927947334,-87.308349609375|45.836454050187726,-88.099365234375|45.67548217560647,-88.681640625|47.99727386804474,-88.90960693359375|48.00872694070618,-89.422384747362|48.078505101664575,-90.037619122362|48.1481887505854,-90.652853497362|48.10785710345748,-90.740744122362|48.225097592060386,-90.872580059862|48.078505101664575,-91.268087872362|48.08217501817276,-91.575705059862|48.19215079157971,-91.861349591112|48.34937203373956,-92.0645966614245|48.33841880508485,-92.300802716112|48.23607514890092,-92.333761700487|48.331115344958384,-92.4820771301745|48.4838455701099,-92.8289794921875|48.596807287341846,-93.0212861982888|48.527734567191324,-93.5541231123513|48.54228403147538,-93.8177949873513|48.658529250749524,-94.1913301436013|48.72742329875959,-94.5923311201638|48.78536623015411,-94.9933320967263|48.87215533860201,-95.2405244795388|48.886605576629925,-95.6360322920388|48.78898544442703,-96.0205537764138|48.73104669003351,-96.44567453376897|48.76002442116329,-96.97301828376897|48.556829314722485,-97.20373117439397|48.05994259338911,-97.20373117439397|47.73584772768336,-97.09386789314397|47.40972298357073,-96.98400461189397|47.08156627951654,-96.87414133064397|46.901714603324805,-96.89611398689397|46.85665710610569,-97.45641672126897|46.87168047601221,-98.25841867439397|46.856657106105665,-99.59875070564397|46.84162953184038,-100.93908273689397|46.84914384452681,-101.35656320564397|46.84162953184038,-101.70812570564397|46.85942776594315,-102.17122371104136|46.836908509818876,-102.52382337134662|46.836908509818876,-103.17201673072162|46.927018815938936,-103.50160657447162|46.69689933783226,-103.1873880996809|46.55354342736759,-103.1873880996809|46.466590932064314,-103.2972513809309|46.334004985632575,-103.3521830215559|46.201096815989914,-103.4071146621809|46.06786635694667,-103.4620463028059|45.89227322605981,-103.3906351699934|45.71612317089835,-103.3192240371809|45.62399767612874,-103.5114847793684|45.45470708776329,-103.5444437637434|45.28490676739647,-103.5774027481184|45.106843195509484,-103.5609232559309|44.908773558866855,-103.6488138809309|44.70611502538482,-103.8685404434309|44.408641060860944,-103.8575541153059|44.36153247411174,-103.7147318496809|44.2947304163488,-103.4565531387434|44.14907472653383,-103.2807718887434|44.08203102595271,-102.9072367324934|44.089922468098244,-102.6106058731184|44.018861590211884,-102.2920023574934|43.939805054682495,-102.2755228653059|43.85829677916183,-102.3431396484375|44.39294241085277,-104.60455664806784|44.17271904794254,-105.94488867931784|44.014911263473984,-106.60406836681784|43.05922556775775,-106.47223242931784|42.898472569367925,-105.83502539806784|42.70501434121029,-105.19781836681784|41.990496203270155,-105.06598242931784|41.26786671462826,-104.93414649181784|40.537150041291156,-104.80231055431784|39.84900208721642,-105.00006446056784|39.66893673818376,-105.3988234468572|39.580290274408675,-106.34765625|39.6479973237342,-106.9189453125|39.54641191968676,-107.666015625|39.257778150283386,-108.2373046875|39.2067188449185,-108.80859375|38.950865400920016,-109.423828125|38.96795115401596,-110.006103515625|38.91670933461174,-110.58841463386983|38.83117764105863,-111.08279939949483|38.745543050043906,-111.57718416511983|38.91670933461174,-112.02762361824483|38.48802257459572,-112.25833650886983|38.246836818905756,-112.28030916511983|38.0913647261547,-112.39017244636983|37.86620899033695,-112.50003572761983|37.64036318932431,-112.60989900886983|37.837234243696585,-112.91134807934924|38.536678009385675,-112.71359417309924|39.08456354876798,-112.38400432934924|39.62822655463809,-112.24118206372424|39.94549031786236,-111.84303557030785|40.64933613443504,-111.88698088280785|41.16413074975152,-111.95289885155785|41.740527438925064,-112.18361174218285|42.39298713963626,-112.27150236718285|43.04676320574944,-112.48024260155785|43.89190598131474,-111.65626799218285|44.40430574956993,-111.35963713280785|44.57672567556643,-110.73341642968285|45.06021210175154,-111.05509703772327|45.392932919133095,-111.36271422522327|45.5914397852913,-111.2272268844116|45.83308632726237,-111.3590628219116|45.89429051706444,-111.6502005172241|45.875171445875104,-112.1226126265991|45.97451876492385,-112.4796682906616|46.23730877687327,-112.29848821416527|46.225909172465585,-112.15017278447777|46.445881955651835,-112.00735051885277|46.706421459451924,-112.01284368291527|46.965709503439555,-112.02383001104027|47.2871292803084,-112.16665227666527|47.487958699120846,-112.38637883916527|47.7840778067928,-112.15566594854027|47.96094405046076,-112.29848821416527|48.11520697297621,-112.45778997197777|48.331129770891934,-112.59511907354027|48.444215824815956,-112.85879094854027|48.535231252839395,-113.13344915166527|48.62971404201499,-113.33120305791527|48.75981008089207,-113.7908935546875|48.63288072674892,-113.91710986447083|48.436461988506586,-114.02697314572083|48.36352088141846,-114.24669970822083|48.12940624138611,-114.37853564572083|48.033990970339815,-114.73009814572083|47.96783055551521,-115.12560595822083|48.158729184570966,-115.43322314572083|48.40000450860535,-115.82873095822083|48.61835731972006,-116.18029345822083|48.3416461723746,-116.16943359375|48.3416461723746,-116.16943359375|48.026672195436014,-116.54296875|47.628380027447164,-117.09228515625|47.54687159892241,-117.652587890625|47.32393057095946,-117.97119140625|47.10004469402522,-118.289794921875|47.077604117159666,-118.883056640625|47.05515408550351,-119.476318359375|47.18971246448423,-119.794921875|47.040182144806685,-120.146484375|47.11499982620777,-120.76171875|47.353710619513684,-121.35498046875|47.59134647679717,-121.9482421875|47.554286701279636,-122.244873046875|47.66538735632665,-122.508544921875|47.680182946484265,-123.123779296875|47.46523622438362,-123.486328125|47.16730970131579,-123.11279296875|46.89773908550703,-122.926025390625|46.5135155805974,-122.838134765625|46.12655630241854,-122.816162109375|45.96600815877737,-122.92422826901486|45.92017061779385,-122.82535131588986|45.76710508706392,-122.69351537838986|45.61361838795423,-122.56167944088986|45.44429650490584,-122.46280248776486|45.35944441557727,-122.63858373776486|45.19710017865486,-122.84732397213986|44.92549423676863,-122.99014623776486|44.43422116708742,-123.1134398409618|44.0485599542741,-123.0255492159618|43.66831867550607,-123.2452757784618|43.33361894347486,-123.3771117159618|42.932748526101506,-123.3111937472118|42.71518628771983,-123.3002074190868|42.44823748537619,-123.2342894503368|42.34666976991593,-122.79149920004869|42.27354905657568,-122.72558123129869|42.10260380698523,-122.64867693442369|42.00032514831621,-122.5634765625|41.82864200186054,-122.552490234375|41.65649719441145,-122.62939453125|41.599013054830216,-122.76123046875|41.541477666790286,-122.89306640625|41.31082388091817,-122.8271484375|41.29431726315256,-123.22265625|41.269549502842565,-123.57421875|41.06437663155705,-123.65915044985468|40.94000852397858,-123.63717779360468|40.74725696280421,-123.255615234375|40.57224011776902,-122.420654296875|40.43858586704331,-122.2998046875|40.304665382591786,-122.178955078125|40.111688665596006,-122.2119140625|39.85072092501602,-122.23388671875|39.58875727696553,-122.255859375|39.317300373271124,-122.1240234375|39.044786048501535,-121.9921875|38.77121637244283,-121.8603515625|38.496593518947684,-121.728515625|38.52238409020095,-121.5087890625|38.45358870894151,-121.17919921875|38.33303882235469,-120.838623046875|38.30718056188316,-120.728759765625|38.11727165830543,-120.640869140625|37.92686760148135,-120.552978515625|37.82280243352756,-120.377197265625|37.71859032558816,-120.179443359375|37.71859032558818,-119.959716796875|37.52693597031617,-120.03652961462802|37.42230798274,-119.72748335243881|37.34395908944491,-119.2236328125|37.34395908944491,-119.2236328125|37.317751851636885,-118.85009765625|37.36142550190517,-118.509521484375|37.28279464911045,-118.27880859375|37.1165261849112,-118.23486328125|36.85325222344019,-118.19091796875|36.55377524336091,-118.10302734375|36.25313319699074,-118.01513671875|36.3770678398369,-117.740478515625|36.50963615733049,-117.081298828125|36.50963615733049,-117.081298828125|36.34167804918316,-116.78466796875|36.27970720524019,-116.466064453125|36.182224980422546,-116.30126953125|35.98689628443794,-116.19140625|35.79108281624999,-116.246337890625|35.594785665487315,-116.30126953125|35.36217605914688,-116.070556640625|35.20972164522146,-116.092529296875|35.083955579276505,-116.279296875|34.939985151560485,-116.531982421875|34.867904962568794,-116.87255859375|34.79576153473041,-116.96044921875|34.48844783780938,-116.905517578125|34.397844946449915,-116.817626953125|34.361576287484226,-116.553955078125|34.189085831172456,-116.466064453125|34.07996230865881,-116.400146484375|33.87953701355925,-115.90576171875|33.87953701355925,-115.90576171875|33.87953701355925,-115.90576171875|33.68372144278084,-115.48663933501376|33.579465985325605,-114.76034561835371|33.616069915721255,-113.26620499335371|33.54284652362709,-111.99179093085371|32.69633189404618,-111.35458389960371|31.486378845391897,-110.98104874335371|30.847142936287803,-110.89315811835371|30.677130361043766,-110.84218422836159|30.31740791729202,-111.06191079086159|29.134407172367098,-110.88612954086159|28.614903668660965,-109.90834633773659|28.30582915679121,-108.89760415023659|28.459033019728043,-108.1494140625|28.526622418648124,-107.171630859375|28.372068829631637,-106.402587890625|28.188243641850313,-106.248779296875|27.868216579514105,-105.985107421875|26.93186515638894,-105.64453125|26.244156283890806,-105.457763671875|26.106120832355543,-104.996337890625|25.671235828577093,-104.666748046875|25.185058883580723,-104.43603515625|24.657002173279132,-104.600830078125|24.076559120295475,-104.490966796875|23.714953506990344,-104.007568359375|23.5035518974242,-103.150634765625|23.301901124188955,-102.952880859375|22.907803451058456,-102.623291015625|22.725523811089488,-102.23876953125|22.471954507739287,-101.53564453125|22.20774917841092,-101.0302734375|21.963424936844312,-100.7666015625|21.483740907163348,-100.61279296875|21.002471054356818,-100.458984375|20.519644202729065,-100.30517578125|20.313720903878068,-99.99755859375|20.055931265194562,-99.6240234375|19.704657579362436,-99.722900390625|19.352610894378767,-99.678955078125|19.290405639498143,-99.42626953125|19.300774825859104,-99.063720703125|19.290405639498143,-98.701171875|19.197053439465,-98.45947265625|19.041348796589165,-98.15185546875|19.04452203291036,-97.89178013809402|18.951030800630146,-97.70501255996902|18.784694895051533,-97.33147740371902|18.826294333168754,-96.67229771621902|18.420263640132095,-96.23284459121902|18.274273783315895,-95.93621373184402|18.649425856403752,-95.56267857559402|18.482792877858987,-95.13421177871902|18.117719676602686,-94.71673130996902|18.044613088936522,-93.96966099746902|17.940122395502065,-93.16765904434402|17.929669925697073,-92.79412388809402|17.678626261868303,-92.08001255996902|17.78327070310832,-91.71746373184402|18.28470571732435,-91.33294224746902|18.57654396020167,-90.86053013809402|18.56612971375347,-90.01458287246902|18.472372919918865,-89.11370396621902|18.701465211647896,-88.28972935684402|19.14432818506539,-88.06023226904404|19.889886878480596,-87.79656039404404|20.240748542228562,-87.47795687841904|20.734734311201954,-87.19231234716904|20.74500870135227,-88.13713656591904|20.755282393701695,-89.08196078466904|20.940089210052996,-89.58733187841904|22.17640838257815,-89.2010517419061|23.512811005111047,-87.9925556481561|24.875663220517428,-85.8392353356561|24.915524974708603,-85.0482197106561|24.895595706418156,-83.9056415856561|24.955373850895064,-82.5543232262811|25.29437116258816,-80.9033203125|26.814266197561462,-80.39794921875|28.13981591275445,-80.70556640625|29.81205076752506,-81.58447265625|31.38177878211098,-81.54052734375|32.778037985363675,-80.70556640625|34.17090836352573,-79.73876953125|35.03899204678081,-78.9697265625|35.897950193357595,-77.98095703125|38.88248119755085,-77.14599609375|38.824961714032675,-76.99821031969634&amp;markers=icon:http://192.168.1.194/public/images/g-pin-icon.png|size:mid|44.30293238565196,-68.2665974476563&amp;markers=icon:http://192.168.1.194/public/images/r-pin-icon.png|size:mid|38.824961714032675,-76.99821031969634&amp;markers=color:red|size:mid&amp;maptype=roadmap&amp;sensor=false&amp;key=AIzaSyCROTlQkfNOnb5oZxUTCXPvz9Dz_xwRXzo" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check the response header to figure out what is wrong with your static maps request.

> The Google Static Maps API may issue an error or warning when something goes wrong. You should check for warnings in particular if you notice that something is missing from the map. It's also a good idea to check for warnings before launching a new application. Note that the warnings may not be immediately apparent because **they appear in the HTTP header.**

source: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/intro#Moreinfo

The `X-Staticmap-API-Warning` header will contain explanation about error or warning. As I can see in the documentation there are certain limits for the number of geocoded locations or the number of polyline vertices (15). This is documented in

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/error-messages#warnings

I hope this information might help to troubleshoot your issue.

**UPDATE**

Static Maps URL from your example is too long. It contains 16187 symbols. The Static Maps API restricts a maximum length of the URL to [8192 characters](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/maps-static/intro#url-size-restriction). The sample URL gets an error

[image]

If you need so long path you should implement encoded polyline calculation as described in

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/utilities/polylinealgorithm

and apply it in your URL.

I created a simple JavaScript code that converts your coordinates to encoded polyline. You can see it on https://jsfiddle.net/xomena/tqv2zsq0/. The encoded polyline has 3064 characters that is within allowed limit.

Now you can use it in the URL as shown in this code snippet (run it to see result)

```html
<img src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=250x200&path=color:0xff0000ff|weight:2|enc:i|kmGfit_LjpFhc_A`kJpg{AlkJpg{AvkJpg{A~|\|j_AzxTz{D`cQhoFfrO~zKnoLhnc@t~X~zKj{g@rst@~HzmoAjnIhxv@`dYph~@tc]fwsAqa`@rkiB_jIpm{Btl]btjDuwRzv_CgoAzv_CfeApqnBlwBrst@~vMpytAysDfl}AysDfl}AviDnwnCw_Y|xeAv|GtxJ~uH_fBdfN~sHvfN~sHiwE|re@ewEhyYi`A|kb@zvSra{@hyDren@owE|yh@xbKh|i@l{@hcm@n{@fcm@dwf@hcm@np`@|nr@reKria@xxLhdPdqUrlq@t`Lhg`@mrl@fniBwsaDgl}A{oaBe`dCsw\oy{DaxdAke|FshSetjDztw@ox~@_hPom{BsnYo}nDq_c@}e{@wmu@ixv@cdr@sen@osqA}`l@_pb@{~eBo|N}xeAykAqg{AokS}trAe`iAff}@ijDra{@{qWckX{wNutWeaIirV{kBs{ZebF}d_@_bF_e_@{aF}d_@umMiyYe|UuxJeoDswg@wqDg`]pgA_ho@m~mAnp`A?fl}AryWfppAn{WfppAj}WfppAh_XfppAdaXfppAbcXfppA~dXfppA|fXfppAxhXfppAtjXfppAxbGtpoBdmXfppA|_f@||x@jpL~re@nrUz~eB|sUz~eBjuU|~eB|vUz~eBjxU|~eBgl`@ddwBaaiAxb`EiqhAluhEmahAnuhEizMbbqDbte@znyCrxe@znyC`m^dvpBendMxok@sfAxccBcsLfdwBorLddwB`{FhdPw{U~vXds[|flA}Ura{@inTfxv@su]huf@lcAfcm@r~R~lE_qQ~}[qy\bwbA_aU|pd@vnLdagB}yA|nr@quUr}gAqmLfimAeiJfimAm}O|go@iyA|flAbaRfbjAbiJ~_rAatD|~eB|tf@|`l@p``B?ph~@smThu~@umT|a_AsmTbcb@hhCpxG|llB{|Ans{Cz|A`xdG||A`xdG}m@fppA|m@htcAgnBhmyAvkCvzcA?fr}BerP|j_Af}k@{j|@~~Z?l~OrmTt{XhvIr}XhvIt_YjvInha@i}L|ka@k}Lv~Prpd@`a`@~lEfd`@~lE|wa@_fB|te@hdPpqf@h|i@fby@ucAleHs{Zn`Lslq@jm[sia@~aLq}gAip@}|x@b{Lif}@`mN_fBl|NreLolgBztxLj_j@`xdGhy]zv_C~syD_wXvk^om{Bbxd@qm{BtpjC_wXlclC}vX~umC_wX|keC|re@jdb@f{lA`iPfixDefLpqnB|yRd|pC|jw@nqnBb~HpqnB`~p@fdwBwiBdvpBf_IlvpBpuO|p_BfvOzp_Byl`@f~vAhvrA~`l@jbn@hhCvj]rmTd~j@tmTpbk@rmTmme@`{y@qrgC_se@g_jB}j_A}diBs{Z{}|@kwlAanhCrqGmpcB~zKoqoB|`l@{l~BhdPau~Brwg@eadDy|_DoacB}|x@st`@{hyBwl}Any}@o~_Apa{@uwe@wmYien@|vXo}Jrzw@nvBpg{A}kRrvdAmir@kkb@ffA_~[y}i@s{Zk{q@ha@qsq@tcA{w}@r{Zeff@h|i@wyx@}`l@kpa@r{Zec]rb^odi@hyYyaU|nr@ywPrst@omQ|re@clX`xxAhxWzsWrje@rmTzfMh|i@dvl@~vXjsQftcAn|K|flAchd@pa{@}bn@|flAwsi@ftcAl`u@{bA??ro|@r}gAhxlAfhjBl|NzllBjpj@ff}@hvj@ff}@fkC|zrBhkCzzrB_hYff}@pe\ftcAsrMfdwB}rm@zzrBglm@zzrBrfF||x@kuT|nr@m{AfdwBj~h@|xeA`ey@s}gAxss@gnc@j`jAkdPnqjAihClj^lbTn}G_iRr{\}vXh~\_wXfa`@_iRjqOria@ru^rwg@p`t@t{Zl}~ApaWjijAidPngiAh|i@zj`A|vXlhmA_{Kvni@scAlcs@_{KxyRmnuA~gM_{Klk`@s_Nd~RosO`p`@ucAzr`@r_NhfJ~vXpfJ~vXr`l@_{KbfB|flAxyCftcAhag@xqOhhWihCtsd@woiAzda@qabDhbYirV~cYgrVbud@|lE`~q@jhCfdr@hhCr_t@_wXdft@}vXxlt@_wXlst@}vXe`Di|i@|lL}j_AlpVsoaAr`DsmT|ad@idP~dd@idPliSsia@hjS_se@?g|i@xld@`_N|lSqj{@thNalaB??xbDq}gA_pGsoaAnjN}`l@bn_@uqGnlr@sqGtny@idP`vy@idPseWsst@q{X{v_C??vx_@}|x@hbKif}@h`R}d_@vce@smTzfe@hvIxie@hvIxll@}`l@zw\hhC~pWhnc@xb[fjp@paMroaAzaMhdPt_{@ivIhuPidPraF}nr@`u`@kdP`iT}zKrcf@}p_B????zfe@ozpApjSizlCwcFmybHrhMa|wFvidDqm{BdikFq}gAfz{BidPpe`@s}HfgeAh|i@v`fFsia@|mdBc~}Dtj{@eldEo|\ecqCmeLc~}D|d]oeuC|{b@i`]bo}@}nr@d{uDsoaAdieCinc@v}Y{byA~|sA}j_Ar}}A}`l@jcfB|d_@vjpBsmT`seAgl}Afhh@{jfDhkf@}re@b~kA}j_Afrb@gbjAxop@qihCfrr@quaB`vn@}nr@~t|Ai`]|~|Ai`]th}Ag`]~eg@sa{@djq@s}gAlrcA~hRhwcAsqGvcKijp@w_A}xeAv_A}xeAnfQsen@bl]qa{@yRoxq@hgQinc@rn_@q}gA_cG{v_CthnAsytAlo[}|x@wghAq}gAnp_@}trAthfAgppA|gMe|pC`lSos{Ch`As}gA~_p@enjC_mS}xeA_}`BgbjA}~w@qg{A``AefdD~hQo}nD{vk@y|_D{nuAkyk@wrpC}nr@{ocAgf}@kn_Bixv@g_AdpwDe_AbpwDabc@puaB_npFgmjAo_dGa`kFydiGgqcLcxF{nyCn{Bcd~EqtJw|fGweaAwmaIkzgHquaBu{aGra{@mreIbtjDyqqHsqGsuoGoabDm`oGoy{DophDoeuCowfDyb`Ei|eQoabDnfJuz[&markers=icon:http://192.168.1.194/public/images/g-pin-icon.png|size:mid|44.30293238565196,-68.2665974476563&markers=icon:http://192.168.1.194/public/images/r-pin-icon.png|size:mid|38.824961714032675,-76.99821031969634&markers=color:red|size:mid&maptype=roadmap&sensor=false&key=AIzaSyCROTlQkfNOnb5oZxUTCXPvz9Dz_xwRXzo" />
```

There is still a warning message and you can check it in browser network console as I explained in the first part of my answer.

[image]

So the warning says

`x-staticmap-api-warning: Failed to fetch image url http://192.168.1.194/public/images/g-pin-icon.png`

Google cannot fetch your custom icon, because it is not available publicly, the 192.168.1.194 is your internal IP address. You have to publish your icons on publicly available hosts in order to avoid this warning messsage.

Comment: How to send large number of map coordinate of markers with this API to draw static map

Comment: The URL is limited to 8192 characters (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/intro#url-size-restriction), so you should be able to send many points. However if something is going wrong you should troubleshoot as I described in my answer to figure out what is wrong with your request. We cannot know this without having your code that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Is there any way to do this ?

Comment: Post example of the request that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: Image doesn't help. We cannot see response and check HTTP header. Post the URL that we can use to reproduce the issue.

Comment: I have added my Google Static Map Image URL.

Comment: I updated my answer, please have a look at explanations.

Comment: Thanks for your solution.

Comment: @xomena, thanks for sharing. The Google encoder really helped me out, thank you!